# Zipfile created with ZipArchive unzips to cpgz

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have this page where you're going to be able to download multiply files to a zip. In my code this works fine, but when I'm trying to unzip it, it unzips to filename.zip.cpgz.

It might have something to do with the fact that I use WordPress, because I tried this before without it and then it worked fine...

When I open the file in a text editor I get following error messages:

> **Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for unstraight.zip in **/Users/johannaskogh/Desktop/workspace/olivia_schough/wp-content/themes/schoughs/page-research.php** on line **16**
>   
>   **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/johannaskogh/Desktop/workspace/olivia_schough/wp-content/themes/schoughs/page-research.php:16) in **/Users/johannaskogh/Desktop/workspace/olivia_schough/wp-content/themes/schoughs/page-research.php** on line **16**
>   
>   **Warning**:  readfile(unstraight.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/Users/johannaskogh/Desktop/workspace/olivia_schough/wp-content/themes/schoughs/page-research.php** on line **18**
>   
>   **Warning**:  unlink(unstraight.zip): No such file or directory in **/Users/johannaskogh/Desktop/workspace/olivia_schough/wp-content/themes/schoughs/page-research.php** on line **19**

Here's the code handling the zip, on the top of the file:

```
<?php

$error = ""; //error holder
if(isset($_POST['createzip'])) {
    $files = $_POST['files'];
    $zipname = time() . ".zip"; // Zip name
    $zip = new \ZipArchive(); // Load zip library
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    // push to download the zip
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    ob_clean();
    readfile($zipname);
    unlink($zipname);
}
?>
```

And here is the rest of it:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article class="article article--about theme">
    <div class="article__part--bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="article__title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
            <div class="article__content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>            
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article__content">
            <form name="zips" method="post">

                <?php
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

                // path to directory
                $directory = $upload_dir['path'] . '/research/';
                $iterator = new \DirectoryIterator($directory);
                ?>

                <div class="checkbox-list">
                <?php foreach ($iterator as $file) {
                    if ($file->isFile()) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="checkboxes">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="<?php echo $file->getFilename(); ?>">
                            <h3 class="font-maxima">"<?php echo $file->getFilename(); ?>"</h3>
                            <span class="smaller-font">The Unstraight Museum</span>
                        </div>

                    <?php

                    }
                }
    <input type="submit" name="createzip" value="Download as ZIP">
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I also tried to change

`$file->getFilename(),`

to

`$file->getRealPath();`

in

`<input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="<?php echo $file->getFilename(); ?>">`

Then the zip could get unziped as it should be,  but the problem here is that I get the whole path to my file, which I don't want. I just want the file/files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I manage to solve to problem, which was that I didn't have a path to the folder.

I changed the `value`  in the form to `$file->getRealPath(); ?>">`

And to make sure the whole path to the file didn't get along in the zip-file, I added `$zip->addFile($file, basename($file));`